# Sotp publishing tf /odom from Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've asked a related question when I needed to put gmapping, laser_scan_matcher and stageros working together.
The problem was that but stageros and laser_scan_matcher publish the odom->base_footprint.
I solved the problem by going to the stageros.cpp and stop the publish of the transform.

But know I want to make a more evolved simulation including IMU and Cameras and wanted to try Gazebo, but the same problem occurs and I cannot find where modified Gazebo to stop publishing.

Has anyone had the same problem???

Thanks in advance

P.S. I think will look in the Pr2 simulation perhaps there they have a similiar problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11796/sotp-publishing-tf-/odom-from-gazebo/) by [fmarques](https://answers.ros.org/users/1293/fmarques/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quickest way to do this is to remap the topic to an unused one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0